# How to make one column match duplicates in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This problem is out of my ability range and I can’t get anywhere with it beyond knowing I can probably use `LEAD`, `LAG` or maybe a cursor?

Here is a breakdown of the table and question:

`row_id` is *always* an `IDENTITY(1, 1)` column.

The `set_id` column always starts out in groups of 3s (two 0s for the first `set_id`, don't worry about why).

The `letter` column is alphabetic. There are varying counts of duplicates.

Here's the original table:

| row_id | set_id | letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | A |
| 2 | 0 | A |
| 3 | 1 | A |
| 4 | 1 | B |
| 5 | 1 | B |
| 6 | 2 | B |
| 7 | 2 | B |
| 8 | 2 | C |
| 9 | 3 | C |
| 10 | 3 | C |
| 11 | 3 | D |
| 12 | 4 | D |
| 13 | 4 | D |
| 14 | 4 | D |

What I need is a code that: if there is a duplicate letter in the next row, then the set_id in the next row should be *the same as the previous row* (`alt_set_id`).

If that doesn't make sense, here is the result I want:

| row_id | set_id | letter | alt_set_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | C | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | C | 2 |
| 10 | 3 | C | 2 |
| 11 | 3 | D | 3 |
| 12 | 4 | D | 3 |
| 13 | 4 | D | 3 |
| 14 | 4 | D | 3 |

Here's where I am with code so far, I'm not really close but I think I am on the right path:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE    
        WHEN letter = [letter in next row]
            THEN 'yes'
        ELSE 'no'
    END AS 'next row a duplicate?',
    'tbd' AS alt_row_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         LEAD(letter) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) AS 'letter in next row'
     FROM 
         sort_test) AS dt
WHERE 
    row_id = row_id
```

That query has the below result set, which is something I think I can work with, but it doesn't feel very efficient and I'm not yet getting the result needed in the alt_set_id column:

| row_id | set_id | letter | letter in next row | next row a duplicate? | alt_set_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | A | A | yes | tbd |
| 2 | 0 | A | A | yes | tbd |
| 3 | 1 | A | B | no | tbd |
| 4 | 1 | B | B | yes | tbd |
| 5 | 1 | B | B | yes | tbd |
| 6 | 2 | B | B | yes | tbd |
| 7 | 2 | B | C | no | tbd |
| 8 | 2 | C | C | yes | tbd |
| 9 | 3 | C | C | yes | tbd |
| 10 | 3 | C | D | no | tbd |
| 11 | 3 | D | D | yes | tbd |
| 12 | 4 | D | D | yes | tbd |
| 13 | 4 | D | D | yes | tbd |
| 14 | 4 | D | NULL | no | tbd |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why rows 13 and 14 have alt_set_id = 3?

Comment: Hey! That table you're referring to I just created. There could be deeper incorrect logic in my question though.

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML (or a DBFIDDLE) you make it much easier for people to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example data, you want the minimum `set_id` for each letter.  If so, use window functions;

```
select t.*, min(set_id) over (partition by letter) as alt_set_id
from sort_test t;
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply! You guys are both correct, but I left out that I need the set_ids to not be altered from groups of 3+. That's my mistake. See my comment to @Stu.

Comment: @SashaSQL . . . In that case, this should do what you want.

Comment: Ok, I had a chance to test and this works brilliantly as long as the letter column does get out of order. Why was I making is so complex...

Comment: @SashaSQL . . . This should really be better than a correlated subquery, which is why I answered.

Comment: And actually issues of letters being out of order--causing the alt_set_id to be non-linear---are resolved by partitioning by row_id.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear if I understand correctly a simple correlated subquery will give you the desired result:

```
select *, (select Min(set_Id) from t t2 where t2.letter=t.letter) as alt_set_id
from t
```

See [working DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b9d3b60f8c0537eeff9748befa2d8a7)

Comment: Thanks! I think the issue would be, then, if the letters in the first three rows were A, B, C, then I would get three alt_set_ids (0, 1, and 2) instead of keeping set_ids to groups of 3+. Does that make sense?

Comment: Revise your sample data and desired results to demonstrate this (and all) edge cases!